# In Laravel Eloquent can I define a many-to-many relationship without a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relational-database

I have a table that is linked to multiple other tables in a many-to-many fashion.

In my example, pmds (primary medical doctors) are records in the `users` table that

1. have a `role_id` that corresponds with `pmd` in the `roles` table; AND
2. are associated with the `sites` table through the intermediate table `site_user`; OR
3. are associated with the `agency` table through the intermediate table `agency_user`

The following function in `User.php` gets the information I want...

```
    public function allPmds()
    {
        return User::whereHas('role', function ($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'pmd');
        })->where(function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('siteUsers', function ($q) {
                $q->where('site_id', $this->id);
            })->orWhereHas('agencies', function ($q) {
                $q->where('agency_id', $this->agency_id);
            });
        });
    }
```

But what I really want is eager loading. Something like this:

```
public function pmds()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->where( <essentially the same code as above> );
    }
```

Comment: why you need many to many relationship without pivot table? please explain a little more.

Comment: i guess you need many through relationships and everything will be great.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need use many to many polymorphic
see [docs about many-to-many polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)